# Can one function of java return two types in different condition?

Tags: java, string, function

```
public String[] getValue(String keyName) {

    ArrayList arraylist = (ArrayList) value.get(getKey(keyName));

    String[] valueArray = new String[arraylist.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < valueArray.length; i++)
        valueArray[i] = arraylist.get(i).toString();

    return valueArray;
}
```

I want to modify this function to make it easier to use.
If the return String array contains only one element.I want it to be returned in String(not String array) type.

How can I do this in Java?

Comment: Sounds like you want to write python code in Java =P

Comment: I can think of about three or four different ways to work around this issue, and I don't want to post them because they all lead to more headaches down the road. My advice is write your code such that it expects an array (or better yet, stick with your collection...) and if it happens to have 1, so be it. It shouldn't react any different than if it had 4.

Comment: Falmarri you are right. If I could have this program done in python I will not use java to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A project I worked on had to deal with something similar. There were some map-like objects. Each key had zero or more values. But there were some keys where we knew there was exactly one value. Others had at most one. Others had zero or more.

We addressed this by introducing an extension to `Collection`:

```
public class CardinalityException extends RuntimeException {
  ...
}

public interface Values<T> extends Collection<T> {

  /**
   * @return the equivalent of iterator().next() if size() == 1
   * @throws CardinalityException if collection is empty 
   *         or contains more than one element.
   */
  T unique() throws CardinalityException;

  /**
   * @return one element from the collection, or null if empty
   */
  T one();
}
```

So essentially, we always returned a `Values<T>`. If the caller knew there was just one value, it would simply use `unique()` or `one()` depending on whether no value was valid.

For cases where the number of values were not important, we just kept values in the wrapped form.

Comment: pretty similar case as mine.The caller probably knows the return value is one or more than one.Thanks

Comment: @oyss: It would have helped if you'd said so in the question. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 10):

Well, you can declare that the method returns `Object` instead of `String[]`... but that makes it *harder* to use, not easier.

- You can't declare that a method can return type X *or* type Y, unless either X or Y is a supertype of the other (in which case other subtypes could be returned, too)
- You can't declare two methods which differ only in return type

Think about what the calling code would look like, and I think you'll see why it's actually simpler to be consistent.

Of course, you could always create your own `OneOrMany` interface which wrapped up common operations, and could have either a single element or many... but again, I can't see the benefit. (I *can* see the benefit in returning a `List<String>` or an `Iterable<String>` rather than an array though.)

EDIT: Having seen your comment on Dilum's answer, in a situation where the caller has an *expectation* of a single element, I would either create helper methods which allowed that to be expressed for collections or simply have two methods:

```
public Collection<String> getValues()
{
    ...
}

public String getSingleValue()
{
    // Throws an exception if there's more than one
}
```

The latter could *either* go via the former method, or potentially be optimized for the case of expecting (and validating) a single result.

That way it's very clear in the *calling* code what you're expecting and why, and having that expectation validated.

I probably *wouldn't* have introduced a new interface, as that would mean I'd either have to wrap existing collection classes or subclass them (argh). In C# it's easy, as you can just use the `Single()` extension method (along with `SingleOrDefault`, `FirstOrDefault` etc)...

Answer (score 5):

No.

How would you be able to use the return value if it were possible?  What type would you assign it to?

```
XXX foo = getValue(keyName);
^^^
What goes here?
```